# Is this square diagram cocartesian for every regular local ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $R=\{f\in K[X]\mid f(0)=f(1)\}$ the $K$-algebra obtained by pulling back $K[X]\to K\times K$, $X\mapsto (0,1)$ along the diagonal.

Is the induced square
\begin{eqnarray}
Hom(K\times K,L)& \to & Hom(K,L)\\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
Hom(K[X],L) &\to & Hom(R,L)
\end{eqnarray}
of sets cocartesian for every regular local ring $L$? The $Hom$ sets are the sets of $K$-algebra maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for any integrally closed $K$-algebra $L$.

Let $p_1: Hom(K[X], L)\to S$, $p_2: Hom(K[X], L)\to S$ be two maps making commutative what has to be commutative. We want to complete with a map $p: Hom(R, L)\to S$.

Denote by $U=X(X-1)$ and $V=X^2(X-1)$. Then it is easy to see that $R=K[U,V]$ and $V^2=U^3+UV$.

Let $\phi: R\to L$ be an element of $Hom(R, L)$. We first lift $\phi$ to $\phi'\in Hom(K[X], L)$: if $\phi(U)=0$, then $\phi(V)^2=0$, hence $\phi(V)=0$ because $L$ is reduced. This $\phi$ lifts to $\rho: X\mapsto 0$ of $Hom(K[X], L)$ (it also lifts to $\rho': X\mapsto 1$, but $\rho$ and $\rho'$ have the same image in $S$ by the initial commutative diagram). If $\phi(U)\ne 0$. Then $\phi(V)/\phi(U)\in \mathrm{Frac}(L)$ is integral over $L$ because
$$ (\phi(V)/\phi(U))^2=\phi(U)+(\phi(V)/\phi(U)).$$
So $\phi(V)/\phi(U)=a\in L$. Then $\phi$ lift to $\rho : X\mapsto a$ of $Hom(K[X], L)$. In this case the lifting is unique.

Now define $p : Hom(R, L)\to S$ by $p(\phi)=p_1(\rho)$. It is straightforward to check that $p$ is well defined and is compatible with $p_1$ and $p_2$ (the latter is constant as $Hom(K, L)$ is just one point).  In fact, the proof above says that $Hom(R, L)$ is the quotient of $Hom(K[X], L)$ by the equivalence relation which just identifies $X\mapsto 0$ and $X\mapsto 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please let me ask two ignorant things: By $K[U,V]$ you mean precisely $K[X][A,B]/(A-X(X−1), B-X^2(X−1))$, is this true? Secondly, is there a method how you ''guess'' $U$ und $V$ with $R=K[U,V]$? For $f=\sum_{k=0}^na_kX^k$ a polynomial, $f(0)=f(1)$ implies $a_1+\ldots+a_n=0$ but this doesn't let me guess how $U$ and $V$ look like.

Comment: @RonaldBernard: $K[U,V]$ is the sub-$K$-algebra of $K[X]$ generated by $U, V\in K[X]$. As $\deg_X U=2$, every $f(X)\in K[X]$ can be written as $f(X)=\sum_{i\ge 0} (a_iX+b_i)U^i$. If $f(0)=f(1)$, then $a_0=0$. So every $f\in R$ is some $$b_0+\sum_{i\ge 1}(a_iXU^i+b_iU^i)=b_0+\sum_{i\ge 1}(a_iVU^{i-1}+b_iU^i)$$ and thus belongs to $K[U,V]$.

Comment: As for how to guess $U$ and $V$. First it is clear the $U=X(X-1)\in R$. The Euclidean division by $U$ shows that $R=K+UK[X]$. So as generator of $K$-algebra for $R$, we also need $UX=V$. After that, check $U, V$ are enough.

Comment: I understand $R=\mbox{'something of degree $\leq 1$'}+UK[X]$ but why is this something of degree zero?

Comment: Please let me ask one last thing: Ok, $K[U,V]\subseteq K[X]$ is generated by $U$ and $V$ but I can write any finitely generated $K$-algebra as $K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I$. Is the representation of this form for $K[U,V]$ the one I suggested, i.e. $K[X,A,B]/I$ with $I=(A−X(X−1),B−X^2(X−1))$? Thank you again. This is such a great help.

Comment: Polynomials in $R$ have no terms of degree one by considering the condition $f(0)=f(1)$. The structure of $K[U,V]$ is $K[T,S]/(S^2-T^3-TS)$. There is a surjective map $K[T,S]/(S^2-T^3-TS)\to K[U,V]$ taking the class of $T$ (resp. of $S$) to $U$ (resp. $V$). Using Euclidean division by $S^2-TS-T^3\in K[T][S]$, one can show that the kernel is trivial. But in my proof, this result is not used.

Comment: I understand the second part of your comment but not the first sentence, for example $U=X(X-1)=X^2-X$ is in $R$ and has the term $-X$ of degree one. I am sorry to bother you again but I don't understand why the '$\mbox{something of degree $\leq 1$}$' is in fact '$\mbox{something of degree $\leq 0$}$'.

Comment: Sorry I was not very precise. I meant if $f(X)=aX+b+Ug(X)\in R$, then $f(0)=f(1)$ iff $b=a+b$ iff $a=0$ iff $f(X)\in K+UK[X]$.